# Rails JS Copy Function

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I have a simple rails app with a copy to clipboard function using js

button

```
<div class="input-group float-end">
    <input type="text" class="form-control bg-dark text-white" value="<%= text.tocopy %>" id="myInput">
    <button class="btn btn-outline-light" id="btn">
        <i class="far fa-copy"></i>
    </button>
</div>
```

js, which is currently loaded at the bottom of the page underneath the loop in a script tag.

```
<script>
  function copyText(text){
    function selectElementText(element) {
      if (document.selection) {
        var range = document.body.createTextRange();
        range.moveToElementText(element);
        range.select();
      } else if (window.getSelection) {
        var range = document.createRange();
        range.selectNode(element);
        window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
        window.getSelection().addRange(range);
      }
    }
    var element = document.createElement('DIV');
    element.textContent = text;
    document.body.appendChild(element);
    selectElementText(element);
    document.execCommand('copy');
    element.remove();
  }
  
  
  var txt = document.getElementById('myInput');
  var btn = document.getElementById('btn');
  btn.addEventListener('click', function(){
    copyText(txt.value);
  })
</script>
```

the copy button is in the index, and works great on the first but obviously it doesnt work on any subsequent instance.

How can I get the js to fire for each instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Rails i found it easier to use stimulus and simply re use the controller with a unique identifier

```
yarn add stimulus-clipboard
```

app/javascript/controllers/clipboard_controller.js

```
import { Application } from '@hotwired/stimulus'
import Clipboard from 'stimulus-clipboard'

const application = Application.start()
application.register('clipboard', Clipboard)
export default class extends Clipboard {}
```

view

```
<div data-controller="clipboard" data-clipboard-success-content="Copied!">
  <input type="text" value="Click the button to copy me!" data-clipboard-target="source" />

  <button type="button" data-action="clipboard#copy" data-clipboard-target="button">Copy to clipboard</button>
</div>
```

hope that helps anyone else